# Replace Text Component with TextInput Component - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to display the fill in the blanks type component in the application.

For Example: Hi, my name is _______. Some more fill in _______ blanks.

I've a response something like this: `{text: Hi, my name is insert_input. Some more fill in insert_input blanks.}`

```
<Text>{item.text}<TextInput/></Text>
```

I'm little bit of confused, how we can achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be sufficient. [Here is the working code](https://snack.expo.io/GbDY3nvs_)

split the sentence based on the string and add them back to back by keeping text input in between them. Don't add it for the last item.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {

  const string =
    "Hi, my name is insert_input. Some more fill in insert_input blanks.";
  const splitString = string.split("insert_input");

  const modifiedString = () => {
    var newStr = "";
    splitString.map((subStr, i) => {
      newStr =  <Text>
                  <Text>{newStr}</Text> 
                  <Text>{subStr}</Text> 
                  {splitString.length - 1 === i ? null : <TextInput placeholder="________________________"/>}
                </Text>;
    });
    console.log(newStr);
    return newStr;
  };

  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
       {modifiedString()}
      </Text>

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: The TextInput is not rendering with the Text, I think we can't render the TextInput Component inside the Text Component. I think we need to try something else.

Comment: can you explain a little more? The snack above is working fine though.

Comment: Your solution was working fine on the snack above but when we shift from web to android in the snack - TextInput was not showing on the device. I've figured it out why it was not working as we've not set the width & height for the TextInput.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts @Glitch_Znab